# Stop auto formatting in shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, formatting

Is there a way I can stop Wordpress auto formatting everything I enter inside a shortcode tag?

A the moment I want to include a h2, a paragraph and another shortcode, but everytime I do Wordpress wraps each different elemnt in p tags.

Is there a way to remove this so I can format each part individually?

Comment: The `[embed]` shortcode removes all shortcodes, runs alone, and then lets everyone else run through. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/media.php#L1052, + check this http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/26/what-the_content-goes-through/ on what filters are usually applied, `wpautop` may not be the only reason.

Comment: http://ideasandpixels.com/disable-wordpress-auto-formatting-short-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can postpone the `wp_autop` filter which is responsible for wrapping elements in P tags till after shortcodes are rendered:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Comment: This almost worked perfectly apart from the fact it added empty paragraphs between each shortcode. I just used `p:empty{display:none}` and it looks great now. Thanks a lot